# Filter rows based on parameter which selects a column?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm building a report in Visual Studio and would like to have a Parameter which allows me to choose a Department from a predetermined list. Each Department is assigned a number of columns in a table. When the Department is selected they are shown only the columns relevant to their group. I have set this by adding a Column Visibility expression to each column.

However, for certain columns, there are empty rows for certain groups. For example, Row 10 may have content for Accounting but no content for Compliance. I'd like to hide this row if I select Compliance as my department Parameter. This seems to work fine in SQL Server, when I run the query with @Department as an input variable. However, when I transfer this logic to Visual Studio, it doesn't like it. If I select the Parameter for "Compliance," nothing from the table shows up at all, except the relevant column headers.

Is there a better way to approach this? What I've done is create columns which = '1' or '0' for each department. So I have a column named "Compliance", "Legal", etc. and each row, if there's related content for the group, will be assigned a '1' for yes or a '0' for no.

Column names are (example):

```
mt.[Customer Name]
mt.[Address]
mt.[Order #]
mt.[CC Info]
mt.[Confirmation #]
mt.[Misc# Notification]
mt.[Confidentiality]
br.Legal
br.Accounting
br.IR
br.Operations
br.Compliance
```

The parameter type is set to TEXT

```
DECLARE @Department VARCHAR(255)

SELECT * 
FROM   maintable mt
       LEFT OUTER JOIN @BooleanRows br 
                    ON (mt.ID = br.ID2) 
WHERE '1' = (CASE WHEN @Department = 'Legal'
            THEN br.Legal
            WHEN @Department = 'Compliance'
            THEN br.Compliance 
            WHEN @Department = 'Accounting'
            THEN br.Accounting 
            WHEN @Department = 'Operations'
            THEN br.Operations 
            WHEN @Department = 'IR'
            THEN br.IR 
        END)
```

As I said, the query works in SQL Server if I set @Department = 'Legal' or 'Compliance' etc, but does not seem to work in Visual Studio report builder. Also, the dropdown list for the Parameters are capitalized/spelled the exact same way as in the query.

Here's an example image of the result in SSRS Report view, when you filter on the Parameter = Department 1:
[View filtered on Parameter = "Department 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/439lx.jpg)

You see that there are 2 column types - the white BG are the columns that are filtered based on Parameter. The light blue BG are columns that are static. Within the white BG columns, there are 3 rows appearing. Only 2 rows contain data. I want to hide/filter out the row that contains no data for those white columns.

Comment: Its not clear to me what your question is. I think you need to illustrate with images your desired report and your actual report. Also if I am understanding correctly, its the logic in SSRS which isn't working, in which case you need to post that. In my experience when the SSRS logic doesn't work there is a type issue.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I've posted an image and some more detail. Hopefully that helps clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Dale Burrell is correct, it is not clear where you issue lies. What I will say is that (from what I think I understand of your issue) you are better off using Row Visibility in the same way you use Column Visibility to hide the information.

Comment: I've posted an image and some more detail. Hopefully that helps clarify, but your idea to switch the row visibility in the same way might be the best/easiest solution for now.